# Binominal sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n_1}{k} \binom{n_2}{n_3-k} x^k$

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Is there any way to simplify the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n_1}{k} \binom{n_2}{n_3-k} x^k,$$
for fixed integer $n_1,n_2, n_3$?
Of course, if we do not have $\binom{n_2}{n_3-k}$, the answer is simply $(1+x)^{n_1}$. However, this additional factor makes the problem complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not complicated if you know [the gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n_1}{k} \binom{n_2}{n_3-k}\, x^k=\binom{n_2}{n_3} \, _2F_1(-n_1,-n_3;n_2-n_3+1;x)$$

If you do not know about it, do not worry : it will be soon.